# Input text wrapping in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, word-break

Have a look at this JS fiddle in Firefox and Chrome

https://jsfiddle.net/rdsz2thp/

In webkit `'word-break: break-word'` on an `input['text']` will make words wrap internally.  Firefox doesn't support that, but is there a way to get that behaviour?

Example code:

```
.wrappy {
    word-break: break-word;
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 200px;
}

<div class='wrapper'>
    <input type='text' class='wrappy' value="fsdf asdf asdfsadfasdf sdf sdfasd fsdas dfsadf asdf sadfasfd asdf sdf asdf sdfasdf asdf asd fsadfasfd ">
</div>
```

Comment: `<input>` is single line, `<textarea>` is multi-line. So use `<textarea>` instead. Chrome is cheating :)

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` is single line, `<textarea>` is multiline. So use `<textarea>` instead

**HTML**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <textarea class='wrappy'>fsdf asdf asdfsadfasdf sdf sdfasd fsdas dfsadf asdf sadfasfd asdf sdf asdf sdfasdf asdf asd fsadfasfd</textarea>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/rdsz2thp/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use textarea instead, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rdsz2thp/5/).

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <textarea class='wrappy'>fsdf asdf asdfsadfasdf sdf sdfasd fsdas dfsadf asdf sadfasfd asdf sdf asdf sdfasdf asdf asd fsadfasfd</textarea>
</div>
```